# Intersperse an aggregate SUM function with rows from other table

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, partitioning

I have two tables:

```
QuantityUsed       Date
12                 01/01/2013 12:35:00
12                 01/01/2013 13:42:20
243                01/01/2013 17:12:00
33                 03/01/2013 12:04:09
34                 03/01/2013 15:09:01
154                03/01/2013 19:00:03
```

and

```
EventID            Date
1                  01/01/2013 14:02:00
2                  03/01/2013 13:00:01
```

I currently have a query that is performing a simple sum of the first table grouped by DAY,
so that I can see a quantity of of items used grouped by the usage date:
eg.

```
SumOfQuantity      Date

263                01/01/2013
221                03/01/2013
```

I would now like to intersperse this aggregate data with events from Table 2.
eg.

```
SumOfQuantity      Date

24                 01/01/2013
EVENT ID 1         01/01/2013
243                01/01/2013
33                 03/01/2013
EVENT ID 2         03/01/2013
188                03/01/2013
```

I will end up with multiple rows for each day, but this is desirable.

I have played with the OVER function in SQL but I seem to be missing something. Ideally this would be backwardly compatible down to SQL2000 but if not practical then SQL2005 is fine.

Any assistance would be gratefully received.
Many thanks

Comment: That output doesn't make sense. Not least because you're mixing datatypes. As a 3rd column, it's possible

Comment: Ok - a poor example. However I am more concerned with the principle of generating the output than the nuts and bolts. Other than the mixture of data types (corrected) which part of the question doesn't make sense? Thanks.

Comment: this should not be done in SQL. the output you provide should be realized in the presentation layer. If you think not, then explain why you have to do it this way

Comment: Because there could be 100,000 rows participating in the SUM. Its not practical to transport that across the network. Thanks

Comment: @NickWilliams yes, it is if it is aggregated in SQL first. As 3 columns

Comment: @gbn - Not sure what your reply means sorry.